# How to add something to “basename”?

Tags: r

```
File="/data/myfun/my_file.img"
basename(file)
"my_file.img"
```

Is there a way to add “_geo” before the extension and returne:

```
"my_file_geo.img"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Capture the `.img` as a group in the `pattern` argument, then replace it with the substring `_geo` followed by the backreferenced group (`\\1`).

```
sub("(\\.img)", "_geo\\1", basename(File))
#[1] "my_file_geo.img"
```